# Couldn't access sqlplus inside screen session

Tags: linux, sqlplus, gnu-screen

I am new to use `screen` session command. While trying to use `sqlplus` inside `screen` session, the `sqlplus` command hits the following error.

```
$ sqlplus
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot 
         open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It would be really a great if someone help point out the cause and fix.

Comment: Sounds like you're not executing a shell startup file that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @barmar for pointing at the cause of the issue. Pardon me for adding answer to my own question, but adding it here for the benefit of others.

As @barmar pointed out, the `screen` session is missing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment path which was available in the shell environment (csh).

We can manually set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside `screen` session, but that will be time consuming effort if we have to use screen in multiple terminals. So, to automate that following change is added in `.cshrc` (as my shell is csh).

```
if $?LD_LIBRARY_PATH then
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH_SCREEN ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
endif
```

Following change is added in `.screenrc`:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH_SCREEN}
```

This approach can be extended for other missing environment variables in a `screen` session.